# File.open not properly documented or am I missing something?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure if Ruby's `File.open` method isn't properly documented, or I'm missing something.

The `File` class inherits from `IO`, which is where the `open` method seems to be defined. As far as I can tell from the documentation, `File` doesn't seem to override `IO`'s implementation of the `open` method.

The [documentation for `File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) documents the `IO.open` class method as taking a numeric file descriptor argument, presumably an object returned by `IO.sysopen`. However, the apparently undocumented `File.open` method will just take a filename.

For example, this fails and quite rightly so according to the documentation:

```
IO.open('data/actors.list') do |io| 
    #...
end
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
File.open('data/actors.list') do |io| 
    #...
end
```

The trouble is, `File.open` appears to override `IO.open` and has a different interface, but it's not documented --- or at least doesn't appear so.

Am I missing something? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruby documentation is wrong, File.open overrides IO.open in order to accept a filename:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_file.html#File.new

and

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1731075#999707

Comment: I'm glad I found this out as a newbie independently writing my first line of Ruby code! Is there anywhere where I can find more accurate documentation?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't dug in too deep into *why* Ruby-Doc.Org shows it that way (I don't use Ruby-Doc.Org anyway), but this is what [RubyDoc.Info](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/File.open) has to say:

> ## Method: `File.open`
>
> Defined in: `io.c`
>
> - `(File) open(filename, mode = "r"[, opt])`
> - `(File) open(filename[, mode [, perm]][, opt])`
> - `(Object) open(filename, mode = "r"[, opt]) {|file| … }`
> - `(Object) open(filename[, mode [, perm]][, opt]) {|file| … }`
>
> With no associated block, `open` is a synonym for `File.new`. If the optional code block is given, it will be passed file as an argument, and the `File` object will automatically be closed when the block terminates. In this instance, `File.open` returns the value of the block.
>
> ### Overloads:
>
> - `(File) open(filename, mode = "r"[, opt])`
>
>   - Returns: `(File)`
> - `(File) open(filename[, mode [, perm]][, opt])`
>
>   - Returns: `(File)`
> - `(Object) open(filename, mode = "r"[, opt]) {|file| … }`
>
>   - Yields: `(file)`
>   - Returns: `(Object)`
> - `(Object) open(filename[, mode [, perm]][, opt]) {|file| … }`
>
>   - Yields: `(file)`
>   - Returns: `(Object)`

This matches the RDoc comment in the file [`io.c` in the YARV sources](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/io.c#L5409-5423):

```
/*
 *  Document-method: File::open
 *
 *  call-seq:
 *     File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])                 -> file
 *     File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])         -> file
 *     File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
 *     File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
 *
 *  With no associated block, <code>open</code> is a synonym for
 *  <code>File.new</code>. If the optional code block is given, it will
 *  be passed <i>file</i> as an argument, and the File object will
 *  automatically be closed when the block terminates. In this instance,
 *  <code>File.open</code> returns the value of the block.
 */
```

Comment: Is RubyDoc.info an accurate source of documentation, or should I just read the C source?

Comment: RubyDoc.Info is generated from the same C source, that Ruby-Doc.Org is. The main difference is that Ruby-Doc.Org is basically unmaintained for 6 or 7 years now, and has been known to be broken, inaccurate and outdated for at least that long.

Comment: I had no idea! I only found it through http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ There should probably be a warning to that effect on that page!

Comment: @Matty: There's a github project for ruby-lang.org where you could file a bug report.

Comment: @Matty: I've filed a bug report about this at https://github.com/ruby/ruby-lang.org/issues/15